# CollectionViewSource sorting with default and backup sources

Tags: wpf, sorting, collectionviewsource

I am working on a scheduling program in which items have a scheduled date, but the user can elect to override this for a date they choose.  To implement this, my Item object uses two properties:  ScheduledDate (DateTime) and ActualDate (DateTime?).  Therefore, if the ActualDate property is null, the user has not overridden the schedule for this item.

In one of my views, I need to display these items in a `ListBox`, sorted by the actual date.  The trouble I am having is how to implement a `CollectionViewSource` with these two properties.

I know it's not correct, but I need something like this:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="TransactionsViewSource"
                      Source="{Binding ElementName=ThisControl, 
                                       Path=Items}">
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <cm:SortDescription PropertyName="ActualDate ?? ScheduledDate"/>
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

(ThisControl is the name of the `UserControl` that hosts the `ListBox`.)

If I add a second SortDescriptor (like below), I get a list sorted by ActualDate, then by Scheduled Date, which groups all of the overridden items together.  This is not the desired behavior.

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="TransactionsViewSource"
                      Source="{Binding ElementName=ThisControl, 
                                       Path=Items}">
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <cm:SortDescription PropertyName="ActualDate"/>
        <cm:SortDescription PropertyName="ScheduledDate"/>
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a new method in my `UserControl` class that used LINQ to keep the underlying `ObservableCollection` sorted.  I then called this method whenever an item was edited (actual date overridden) or if a new item was added.  Finally, I removed the `CollectionViewSource` from the XAML and bound the `ListBox` to the `Items` property (which I already had as a dependency property).  The result looks like this:

XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ThisControl,
                               Path=Items}"/>
```

C#:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Items",
                                typeof(ObservableCollection<MyItem>),
                                typeof(MyControl),
                                new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

public ObservableCollection<MyItem> Items
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<MyItem>) GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
}

private void SortItems()
{
    Items = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>(Items.OrderBy(i => i.ActualDate ??
                                                                i.ScheduledDate));
}
```

Then I just use `SortItems()` anywhere that the items in the collection or the collection itself changes.

It works perfectly, and I didn't have to create and manage a new property.  I can live with the little bit of overhead that LINQ creates.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to create one more property for the sorting:

```
public DateTime SortingDate
{
    get { return ActualDate ?? ScheduledDate; }
}
```

.

```
<CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    <cm:SortDescription PropertyName="SortingDate"/>
</CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
```

Comment: How do I handle property changes?  What if the user changes the actual date of one of the items?  I'd prefer not to have to manage another property just for sorting.

Comment: That's easy. If you notify for ActualDate or ScheduledDate change just notify for SortingDate too. The only problem could be the dynamically update of view. For that I always suggest reading this article from Dr. WPF: [ItemsControl: 'E' is for Editable Collection](http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/10/20/itemscontrol-e-is-for-editable-collection/).

Comment: Nice link!  I may end up implementing that to solve some other problems I'm having as well.